# How to join 2 excel sheets/CSV files containing following data?

Tags: database, excel, csv, excel-formula

I have 2 excel files containing product data.
First sheet contains general product information for 7000 items in this columns:

```
ItemTitle|SKU|Available|ItemDescription|RetailPrice|Weight|PurchasePrice|DimHeight|DimWidth|DimDepth|CategoryName|Item Brand|Item Color|Item Department|Item Size|Item Style
```

Second sheet contains image URLS for 5800 entries in following columns:

```
SKU|ImagePath
```

Both sheets have common column named SKU. How do I combine these sheets in order to have 5800 entries that contains all columns combined for all products with images only. Been trying different formulas for several days but feel hopeless. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH

Comment: Make a unique list of all SKU. Then use VLOOKUP to extract row data from the first set of data. Then use VLOOKUP to extract row data from the second set of data. If you have rows with the same SKU - that is bad. That means your records are NOT uniquely identified. In that case you might want to consider how to make each row unique, and then use the same VLOOKUP strategy.

Comment: Helpful hint: one of the parameters in VLOOKUP is the column index. Keep in mind that the column index value is 1's indexed (not 0 indexed). I make that mistake all of the time.

Comment: I hope I don't sound confusing. Basically "SKU" column is like a key in database. There are no rows with same "SKU" data. Basically "ImagePath" in one sheet have "SKU" that matches exact same "SKU" in another sheet. All rows have unique "SKU" in given sheet.

Comment: Use a SELECT statement with JOIN. PowerQuery should be able to handle this.

Comment: Without any images or structure, save as csv,  concatenate the two files together the sort as necessary.

Comment: How to concatenate if two files have different amount of rows?

Comment: Ok I did research on vlookup and it looks like it can return only specific column related to a row data I am looking for. What if I would like to search for specific UPC row and then pull data from column 2 to 10 on the same row?